Error when creating Microsoft Graph Subscription
I have installed both "@nestjs/axios": "^3.0.2", and "axios": "^1.6.8", I have a code to create a Microsoft graph subsrtiption for change notification.
Here is my code:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { InjectAxios } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class MicrosoftGraphService {
    constructor(
        @InjectAxios() private readonly axios,
        private readonly authService: AuthService
    ) {}

    async createSubscription(): Promise<AxiosResponse<any>> {
        const accessToken = await this.authService.getAccessToken();

        const subscriptionUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions';
        
        // When creating a subscription for Microsoft APIs, such as for change notifications in message resources,
        // you can include various parameters in the subscription payload.   
        const subscriptionPayload = {
                // My subscriptionPayload
        };

        const headers = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        };

    return this.axios.post(subscriptionUrl, subscriptionPayload, { headers });
    }


import { InjectAxios } from '@nestjs/axios'; throws an error saying “error TS2305: Module '"@nestjs/axios"' has no exported member 'InjectAxios'.”
Any idea why?
